# AspectJ - Aspect from external JAR

Tags: java, xml, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin, microprofile

**I've added a github repo that show exactly my problem:**

https://github.com/runefist/AspectJ-Stackoverflow-Q

---

In short, I have a project we'll call it ProjectA. ProjectA is a microprofile-REST-server. Another project, we'll call this ProjectB, is a dependency for ProjectA (and other projects).

- ProjectA (microprofile-REST-server)
- ProjectB (dependency of ProjectA)

ProjectB contains an Aspect:

```
@Aspect
public class ElasticSenderAspect {

    @After("@annotation(elasticsender)") // && execution(* *(..))
    public void after(JoinPoint joinPoint, ElasticSender elasticsender) {
         WebsiteBehaviour websiteBehaviour = new WebsiteBehaviour();  
         websiteBehaviour.setBehaviourFunc(elasticsender.behaviourFunction());
         websiteBehaviour.setBehaviourType(elasticsender.behaviourType());
         ElasticWebsiteBehaviour.sendWebsiteBehaviour(websiteBehaviour);
    }
}
```

In ProjectA I have a function:

```
@GET
@Operation(description = "Authenticate")
@ElasticSender(behaviourFunction = "Authenticate")
public Response authenticate(@HeaderParam("authorization") String authString) {
    if (authString == null) {
        return StandardResponseMessages.GENERAL_NO_AUTHENTICATION.getResponse();
    }
    WebAccount webAccount = webAccountService.find(getUsernameFromAuth(authString));
    boolean correct = false;
    //TODO: CHECK IF ACCOUNT IS VERIFIED
    if (webAccount != null) {
        if (webAccount.getUsername() != null && webAccount.getPassword() != null) {
            if (AuthenticatorUtility.basicAuthenticate(webAccount.getUsername(), webAccount.getPassword(), authString)) {
                correct = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (correct) {
        return Response.ok(generateTokenString(webAccount)).build();
    } else {
        return StandardResponseMessages.GENERAL_WRONG_AUTHENTICATION.getResponse();
    }
}
```

I've tested the Aspect, which works when I use it in the SAME project, so NOT as dependency.

ProjectA - pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.runefist</groupId>
    <artifactId>FeestjesDoen-Server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>FeestjesDoen-Server</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>BendingHeroes-repo</id>
            <url>xxx</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- MAIN DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.runefist</groupId>
            <artifactId>WebRest-Utilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MICROPROFILE SWAGGER UI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.microprofile-ext.openapi-ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- KAFKA NEEDED -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <encoding>UTF-8 </encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

ProjectB - pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.runefist</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebRest-Utilities</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- MICROPROFILE REPLACES JAVAEE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.microprofile</groupId>
            <artifactId>microprofile</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FOR CREATING JWT TOKENS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FOR THE USE OF HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MYSQL CONNECTOR FOR HIBERNATE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.26</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- FOR JSON CONVERSION -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ElasticSearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>6.5.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- AspectJ | to add behaviour to methods -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Junit - TEMP added to test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                             <!--use this goal to weave all your main classes--> 
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                             <!--use this goal to weave all your test classes--> 
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- put your configurations here -->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Problem:

Aspect happens when tested in ProjectB, aspect does NOT happen when tested in ProjectA. What do I need to add to ProjectA pom to make it work, or what do I need to change to ProjectB pom to make it work?

Comment: I can suggest to move your aspects into some generic jar maven module, and use it in both projects as a dependency. As well as together with [apectj runtime](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjrt)

Comment: Euhm, I don't understand, moving the aspect to another module and adding the module as dependency to other projects, what's the difference of how I have it now? I've added the pom of ProjectA, maybe that helps.

Comment: Ok I got it finally, Project B is actually an aspect library. It seems like you've forgotten to add `aspectj-maven-plugin` to the Project A pom file, so aspect compiler not working on the web service, as well as no aspect code injected by the AspectJ compiler, and all what you have is just an elasticsender annotation.

Comment: Just copy-paste plugin configuration code into Project A, or make move it in the root pom parent module, so that whole modules will have the same.

Comment: I've done that, still does not work, I've created a github repo, which shows exactly the scope I am talking about, you can find it here: https://github.com/runefist/AspectJ-Stackoverflow-Q. I hope this helps solving the problem, if you need any other information, please ask :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In project A you need to add B as an [aspect library](https://www.mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/libraryJars.html) in the AspectJ Maven configuration in addition to adding it as a Maven dependency as you already did:

```xml
            <configuration>
                <!-- (...) -->
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.runefist</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ProjectB</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
```

I cloned and tested your project, it works this way.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution.
I can confirm that it works for my project as well.
I was having the same problem and got it solved with this fix. :)

Answer (score 0):

I've got same problem and adding spring-aop dependency to projectB helped me.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.18</version>
</dependency>
```

And there is no need to add aspectj plugin in projectA, just

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.runefist</groupId>
        <artifactId>ProjectB</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```