# Aspect from external module (for Java + Gradle project) not working

Tags: java, gradle, aspectj, freefair-aspectj

I have put the MCVE code for this on GitHub - https://github.com/ravitechy/multi-module-project/tree/main

I have two modules in my Java project (built on Gradle) - `app` which depends on `commons`.

`commons` contain the Aspect class `BasicCommonAspect` as defined below

```
package org.example.commons.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@Aspect
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class BasicCommonAspect {
           
    @Before("@annotation(bca) && execution(* *(..))")
    public void executeBeforeForCommonAnnotation(JoinPoint joinPoint, BasicCommonAnnotation bca) {
        System.out.println("BasicCommonAnnotation detected");
    }
}
```

`commons` also contain an annotation `BasicCommonAnnotation` like this

```
package org.example.commons.aspect;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface BasicCommonAnnotation {
}
```

`app` contains `AppBackground` and has a method `run` annotated with `BasicCommonAnnotation`

```
package org.example;

import org.example.commons.aspect.BasicCommonAnnotation;

public class AppBackground {

    @BasicCommonAnnotation
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running in background");
    }

}
```

There is a driver class in `app` module named `RunApp` which invokes the `run` method in `AppBackground`

```
package org.example;

public class RunApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final AppBackground background = new AppBackground();
        background.run();
    }
}
```

I am using post-compile weaving (using the Gradle plugin `io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving`) since I need to use Project Lombok.

When I run the `RunApp` class, my aim is to see the method `BasicCommonAspect.executeBeforeForCommonAnnotation()` executed as per the advice defined.

From my preliminary research, I got to know that I need to include the external module as an aspect library in `apps` module. I found a Stack Overflow answer for the exact same problem here - [AspectJ - Aspect from external JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54707562/aspectj-aspect-from-external-jar), but it was for the Maven build. I am looking for exactly similar configuration for my Gradle project.

I tried using `inpath` as suggested here https://github.com/freefair/gradle-plugins/issues/450, but I began running into different build errors now as indicated below.

```
Not skipping AJC (inpath is set)
Starting process 'command 'D:\OpenJdk17\bin\java.exe''. Working directory: D:\intellij-idea workspace\multi-module-project\app Command: D:\OpenJdk17\bin\java.exe -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=IN -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\raviteja.kothapalli\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.aspectj\aspectjtools\1.9.8\caf8b7f9023d93af2ed2e6e8bf023a800e9d1323\aspectjtools-1.9.8.jar org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main -argfile D:\intellij-idea workspace\multi-module-project\app\build\tmp\compileJava\ajc.options
Successfully started process 'command 'D:\OpenJdk17\bin\java.exe''
←[0K
←[0K
←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m===←[0;39;1m----------> 25% EXECUTING [18s]←[m←[35D←[1B←[1m> :app:compileJava←[m←[18D←[1B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m===←[0;39;1m----------> 25% EXECUTING [19s]←[m←[35D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m===←[0;39;1m----------> 25% EXECUTING [20s]←[m←[35D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m===←[0;39;1m----------> 25% EXECUTING [21s]←[m←[35D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m===←[0;39;1m----------> 25% EXECUTING [22s]←[m←[35D←[2B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m===←[0;39;1m----------> 25% EXECUTING [23s]←[m←[35D←[2B←[2AC:\Users\raviteja.kothapalli\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\2.7.18\9cf147c6ca274c75b32556acdcba5a1de081ebcd\spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.7.18.jar [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.web.server.WebExceptionHandler
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.error.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler
when weaving classes
when weaving
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=0 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
(no source information available)
        [Xlint:cantFindType]
←[0K
←[0K
←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m===←[0;39;1m----------> 25% EXECUTING [23s]←[m←[35D←[1B←[1m> :app:compileJava←[m←[18D←[1B←[2A←[1m<←[0;32;1m===←[0;39;1m----------> 25% EXECUTING [24s]←[m←[35D←[2B←[2AC:\Users\raviteja.kothapalli\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.7.18\f6dbdd8da7c2bded63dff9b1f48d01a4923f20a0\spring-boot-2.7.18.jar [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type javax.servlet.Filter
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter
when weaving classes
when weaving
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=0 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
(no source information available)
        [Xlint:cantFindType]
C:\Users\raviteja.kothapalli\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.7.18\f6dbdd8da7c2bded63dff9b1f48d01a4923f20a0\spring-boot-2.7.18.jar [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type io.undertow.server.HttpHandler
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowWebServer$CloseableHttpHandlerFactory$1
when weaving classes
when weaving
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=0 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
(no source information available)
        [Xlint:cantFindType]
C:\Users\raviteja.kothapalli\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.springframework.boot\spring-boot\2.7.18\f6dbdd8da7c2bded63dff9b1f48d01a4923f20a0\spring-boot-2.7.18.jar [error] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter
when weaving type org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.filter.OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter
when weaving classes
when weaving
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=0 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
(no source information available)
        [Xlint:cantFindType]
```

So, what I understood is that I need to include the aspect classes only from specific packages in the `inpath` in order to overcome the issue, but I can't seem to find the configuration to do it.

Please help me in providing the necessary configuration to include the aspects from external JARs/modules only from specific packages.

`build.gradle` file in `apps` module

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving' version "${aspectjVersion}"
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
//    api project(":commons")
    inpath project(":commons")
    api libs.spring.boot.starter
    annotationProcessor libs.lombok
    implementation libs.aspectjrt
}
```

`build.gradle` in `commons` module

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'java-library'
    id 'io.freefair.aspectj.post-compile-weaving' version "${aspectjVersion}"
}

java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
java.targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    api libs.spring.boot.starter
    annotationProcessor libs.lombok
    implementation libs.aspectjrt
}
```

`settings.gradle` in `root`

```
rootProject.name = 'multi-module-project'
include('app')
include('commons')

dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        libs {
            version('spring-boot-ver', '2.7.18')
            library('lombok', 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30')
            library('spring-boot-starter', 'org.springframework.boot', 'spring-boot-starter').versionRef('spring-boot-ver')
            library('aspectjrt','org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.9.8')
        }

        testLibs {
            library('junit-jupiter-api','org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1')
            library('junit-jupiter-engine', 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1')
        }
    }
}
```

`build.gradle` in `root`

```
rootProject.ext {
    projectGroup = 'org.example'
    projectVersion = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
    aspectjVersion = '8.4'
}
```

P.S: Everything is working as expected if all the classes, annotations and aspects are in one single module.

Comment: Thanks for following my advice to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Great job! It is so much easier to help you this way. Please keep up the good practice for all future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `inpath project(":commons")` in your application module. The *inpath* is meant to be used, if you want to weave aspects into a third-party module. The latter would go on the *inpath*. But in this case, you simply want to tell the plugin where to find aspects to weave into the current module. The aspect library, however, belongs on the *aspectpath*.Therefore, you need to change the line to `aspect project(":commons")`. This is the equivalent to `<aspectLibrary/>` from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54719756/1082681) to the corresponding Maven question you already found

I have created a [pull request](https://github.com/ravitechy/multi-module-project/pull/1) for your project, fixing this problem and improving a few other things. Just go through the commit diffs and comments one by one.

Now, you can build and run your application. The console log says:

```
> Task :app:RunApp.main()
BasicCommonAnnotation detected
Running in background
```

I.e., the aspect gets triggered as expected.

Comment: Thanks @kriegaex. `aspect` was what I was looking for. I merged your PR on the git as well.